# Custom select dropdown not working in key up and down

Tags: jquery

I have used a custom jQuery for dropdown. Now its working fine with all browsers except with Mozilla for keyboard up and down events for the dropdown.

I have used following script for dropdown keyboard event.

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
if (!$.browser.opera) {
    $('select.selectlistbig').each(function(){
        var title = $(this).attr('title');
        if( $('option:selected', this).val() != ''  ) title = $('option:selected',this).text();
        $(this)
            .css({'z-index':10,'opacity':0,'-khtml-appearance':'none'})
            .after('<span class="selectlistbig">' + title + '</span>')
            .change(function(){
                var val = $('option:selected',this).text();
                    $(this).next().text(val);
                })
    });

    $('select.selectlistbig').keypress(function (e) {
        if(e.keyCode == 37 || e.keyCode == 38 || e.keyCode == 39 || e.keyCode == 40 )
        {                   
            var val = $('option:selected', this).text();
            $(this).next().text(val);           
        }
    });
});
```

Help me.

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

e.keyCode doesn't work in firefox. Pls try below code using **e.which**:

```
$('select.selectlistbig').keypress(function (e) {
    var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
    if(code == 37 || code == 38 || code == 39 || code == 40 )
    {                   
        var val = $('option:selected', this).text();
        $(this).next().text(val);           
    }

});
```